# conditions for maps between homotopy colimits

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy-theory

Given two diagrams $F_1$ and $F_2$, $C \to Top_{*}$, is there any sufficient condition for the existence of a continuous function on $hocolim(F_1) \to hocolim(F_2)$ where $C$ is a small category. Of course, having a natural transformation between $F_1$ and $F_2$ guarantees the existence of such a map. In my research, I am looking for a map in the twisted setting (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/bondalKaprEnhTRiangCat.pdf). So, in stead of a natural transformation, I have multiple maps $q_{w,u}:F_1(u) \to F_2(w)$. I am looking for  conditions on $ \{ q_{w,u} \} $ that ensures a continuous map on the respective homotopy colimits. Is there reference in the literature?  \par
Thank you so much!

Comment: is there a good answer even in the classical setting? I think it's just going to amount to the universal property of colimits, and for homotopy colimits I think the answer will be basically the same

Comment: You'll need to say more about what conditions are imposed upon these maps $q_{w,u}$. Just on the level of $\infty$-categories, you'll have $\mathsf{map}(\mathop{\mathrm{colim}}F_1,\mathop{\mathrm{colim}}F_2)\simeq \mathsf{map}(F_1,\Delta\mathop{\mathrm{colim}}F_2)$, so if there is such a condition, it's exactly as hard as specifying a natural transformation $F_1\to\Delta\mathop{\mathrm{colim}} F_2$ as maps $N\mathsf{C}\to N^h\mathsf{Top}_{\ast}^\circ$, which is basically what Andres is saying.